# Change the starting value of value axis in Bar chart with Jfreechart

Tags: java, visualization, jfreechart, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have the following values to be shown in a BAR chart in my Java web application.
9.46373791E8
9.45942547E8
9.45559945E8
9.45187023E8
9.44856693E8
9.44417826E8
9.44007878E8

As u can see the values are really close and have minor differences. When i generate a bar chart using Jfreechart, all the bars appear almost the same height and there is no way of telling the difference visually. So i want to change the (0,0) to (0,9)so that x axis is at number 9 on y axis. I still want to show the real values that the bars represent somewhere on top of the bar.

please suggest ideas. i tried the below but it didnt work

```
    Double d=(double) 9;
ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(d);
```

Edit: This is my original program for your reference

```
JFreeChart chart =
            ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                    title,
            "File Date",
            "File Size",
            dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,
            true,
            false);
         chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);



      // Set the background color of the chart
        chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        chart.setBorderVisible(true);
        // Adjust the color of the title
        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(d);
        // Get the Plot object for a bar graph

        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);     
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.blue);
        CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#00008B"));
```

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116635).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want to do the following:

```
barChart.getCategoryPlot().getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(9.0);
```

where barChart is you `JFreeChart Object`.

But since yours values are above 9.0E8 ( IT'S OVER 9000), shouldn't you put the lower bound at 9.0E8 instead of 9.0 since at there is not so much difference between 0 and 9 when you are at 9.0E8 and beyond.

EDIT: I've tested your code and it's working on my computer under Windows Vista...

[image: Code output]

My full code is here:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

public class ChartTester extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ChartTester(final String title) {
        super(title);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        final CategoryDataset dataset = createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);

    }

    /**
     * Returns a sample dataset.
     * @return The dataset.
     */
    private CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        final String rowName = "Row";
        final String[] columnName = { "Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4","Column5"};
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(9.2, rowName, columnName[0]);
        dataset.addValue(9.3, rowName, columnName[1]);
        dataset.addValue(9.4, rowName, columnName[2]);
        dataset.addValue(9.5, rowName, columnName[3]);
        dataset.addValue(10.0, rowName, columnName[4]);

        return dataset;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a sample chart.
     * @param dataset  the dataset.
     * @return The chart.
     */
    private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {
        double d =9.0;
        final JFreeChart chart =
            ChartFactory.createBarChart(
                    "Chart Title",
                    "X Axis",
                    "Y Axis",
                    dataset,
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                    true,
                    true,
                    false);
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);  
        // Set the background color of the chart
        chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        chart.setBorderVisible(true);
        // Adjust the color of the title
        CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        plot.getRangeAxis().setLowerBound(d);
        // Get the Plot object for a bar graph
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);     
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.blue);
        CategoryItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.decode("#00008B"));
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ChartTester test = new ChartTester("Test");
        test.pack();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats true. I was gonna do some trial and error once i know how to change the lower bound. Thanks Julien :)

Comment: Julien,I posted my original code here. I was doing the same thing you mentioned in your comment. But somehow, the chart's range axis does not start at 9 or any other value. it only starts at 0,0.

Comment: @DJR I've tested your code and it's working. I added my full code, it's maybe your OS or your Java version the problem. Test my code to check.

Answer (score 1):

Since the y-axis in your example is an instance of `NumberAxis` you can call the method `setAutoRangeIncludesZero()` on the axis (passing false for the new value of the flag).
Then, even if you add new data to the `dataset`, the axis range will be updated correctly (whereas calling `setLowerBound()` will fix the axis range with the lower bound you specify, and disable the auto-range feature).